# Tableau - Excluding Null Values From Multiple Time Series

Tags: date, null, tableau-api

So I have two time series on one time axis. However, the second time series (Exiters) has null data for the last time period (2018 Q3). Tableau is currently dealing with this null data point by extending the series line to to the bottom which ultimately makes it appear to any user that the data has dipped to "0". Extending the line to "0" is misleading in my opinion.

That being said, is there any way to exclude this null data point only without affecting the data in the other time series (Participants)? Basically, I just want to exclude this specific null data point, have the Exiter time series end at 2018 Q2 and maintain the Participant time series ending at 2018 Q3. This surely is possible right?[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK8hO.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my attempts to reproduce this, I kept finding that the default behavior was to act as you are desiring; to have Exiter end at Q2 while Participant displays into Q3.

I was able to reproduce the "0" effect, though, once I clicked on the following button "Show data at default position" after clicking on the "2 Nulls" button at the bottom right of the viz:

[image]

[image]

I wonder if perhaps at some point that button was clicked in the creation of this workbook. More information on default positions [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_specialvalues.htm).

The way to revert this behavior, which may end up giving you the view you are looking for is:

```
Analysis > Special Values > Hide
```

[image]

Comment: Any luck on this? If you were able to solve on your own, can you please post an answer and give yourself the green check mark? This will help others solve this question in the future.